# jquery click event on anchor

Tags: jquery, events, click, href

Here's the snippet of html i have:

```
<div id="tag-cloud-widget">  
    <div class="content">  
        <a href="#" rel="1" class="cloud-element" data-tag-id="10" style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(205, 236, 222); ">T1</a>  
        <a href="#" rel="1" class="cloud-element" data-tag-id="1" style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(205, 236, 222); ">T2</a>  
        <a href="#" rel="1" class="cloud-element" data-tag-id="3" style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(205, 236, 222); ">T3</a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to set up a click handler to respond to the user's click on the anchor tags. Here's the test code:

```
$("#tag-cloud-widget .content a").click(function(e) {
    alert('clicked');  
    return false;  
});
```

The click handler above does not get fired and neither does this:

```
$("#tag-cloud-widget .content .cloud-element").click(function(e) {  
    alert('clicked');  
    return false;  
});
```

However,

```
$("#tag-cloud-widget .content").click(function(e) { ... });
```

and

```
$("#tag-cloud-widget").click(function(e) { ... });
```

do get fired!

What am I not seeing???

Comment: Your first section of jQuery works for me in Chrome and IE 8: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Mx9K/1/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When handling anchor click events, always use `e.preventDefault();` when you don't need the anchor anyway. 
[Fires like a charm](http://jsfiddle.net/LAmym/)

Comment: I actually tried with and without e.preventDefault();  I found out what the problem was. silly thing! Ok, the anchors are created dynamically from a template DOM element. I clone and update the template element's attribute and append it to the tags cloud content. I forgot to call .clone() with the 'true' flag to copy all associated event handlers. Once I changed the code to .clone(true) all worked like a charm :) Thank you and to everyone else who responded so quickly. cheers!

Comment: I'm glad everything worked out for you and you got it all working! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

!THIS is tested and working.

You forgot to put your code inside the document ready function

```
$(function() {
//your code
});
```

Comment: The below two code snippets given in question are working as per what @djeetee says, so that's not the case.

Comment: @Kush you are wrong, the script is placed before the dom content, so it's not applied correctly. I tested with document ready and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your first code doesn't work because there are multiple anchors in your `div content` tag, hence when you associate anchor that resides in that tag with a click, it will generate ambiguity to in choosing exact anchor. You can target particular anchor by using its `id` attribute, and than associate the `id` with your events to target particular anchor. So the code will be as follows.

```
<div id="tag-cloud-widget">  
    <div class="content">  
        <a href="#" rel="1" class="cloud-element" id="anca" data-tag-id="10" style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(205, 236, 222); ">T1</a>  
        <a href="#" rel="1" class="cloud-element" id="ancb" data-tag-id="1" style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(205, 236, 222); ">T2</a>  
        <a href="#" rel="1" class="cloud-element" id="ancc" data-tag-id="3" style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(205, 236, 222); ">T3</a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

And following will associate clicks to particular anchor.

```
$("#tag-cloud-widget .content #anca").click(function(e) {
    alert('Anchor A clicked');  
    return false;  
});

$("#tag-cloud-widget .content #ancb").click(function(e) {
    alert('Anchor B clicked');  
    return false;  
});

$("#tag-cloud-widget .content #ancc").click(function(e) {
    alert('Anchor C clicked');  
    return false;  
});
```

Comment: JQuery should apply the event handler to all elements that match the selector. In this case, the `click` event handler should be applied to all three anchors.

Comment: So how would you differentiate that which anchor was clicked, if all the three anchors share common click method?

Comment: Normally, you'd use the `this` keyword to get the current element, or if you're using JQuery, you can use the `$(this)` to get the JQuery object for the element. So to use your code, you could create the same function for all the elements' click events, and do this: `alert(this.id + " clicked!);`. That would show "anca Clicked" for the first one, and "ancb clicked" for the second one, and so on.

Comment: @Karl Nicoll: Okay so in order to perform particular action `this.id` can be used to differentiate anchors through conditional chain. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Write your code inside `document.ready` and use `e.preventDefault`

Write like given below :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tag-cloud-widget .content a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Clicked');  
        return false;  
    });
});
```