# jqPlot plugin hook click event to axis ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, jqplot

Hallo everybody, 
i want to extend the jqplot plugins such that the axis ticks are tranformed into hyperlinks and/or are hook with click events. i have know idea on how to go about it. it could also any other javascript based charting framework or library.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you stated any other javascript based library, you could take a look at this example, done with HighCharts: http://jsfiddle.net/grVFk/1424/

I hope is usefull.

Comment: But is there also a way to catch the click events of the hyperlinks with jquery?

Comment: @fon: Yes there is.  Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443469/jquery-click-event-on-anchor

Comment: thanks for your response. well i tried to do that but it is now working. please have a look at what i did : http://jsfiddle.net/grVFk/5074/ may i am doing some thing wrong .